# Correctness of two corona test?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let’s say a corona test is correct with `p=0.8`. If I now take two tests. What’s the probability that I get a correct result?

I think thought of `0.8*0.8`, but that makes now sense, since it should not decrease and `0.8+0.8` gives a probability over 1, which makes no sense either. Or maybe that Bayes probability example?

Edit:
I would like to extend my questions: What’s the probability that I am negativ with one and with two tests? There the probability with two should increase if I am actually negative?
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If `0.8` would be the probability of a correct one then `1 - 0.8 = 0.2` would be the probability of a incorrect one
- `0.8 * 0.8 = 0.64` will be the probability that they are **both** correct
- Which means that the reverse: `1 - 0.64 = 0.36` is the probability that **at least 1** is **in**correct
- The probability that they are **both in**correct will be `0.2 * 0.2 = 0.04`
- The probability that **at least 1** is correct will become: `1 - 0.04 = 0.96`
- The probability that **exactly** 1 will be correct will be `1 - 0.64 - 0.04 = 0.32`
- The probability that it will correct **followed by in**correct will be `0.32 / 2 = 0.16`
- It will also be `0.16` for **in**correct **followed by** correct

**NOTE: This is just the math we are ignoring a lot of things here.**

2 important examples (of the many):

- The most common case of wrong results is incorrect testing, so `0.8` for the general population might be e.g. `0.6` for each test in your case if it's always the same person taking the test
- In real life you should not only take the probability of correct or incorrect into account, instead you should use the probabilities of:

  - correct positive
  - correct negative
  - incorrect positive
  - incorrect negative

Answer (score 2):

The probability that both tests are wrong is $(0.2)(0.2)=0.04$. Therefore, the probability that *at least* one of them is right is $1-0.04=0.96$.

This, if course, assumes that both tests are independent.

Answer (score 0):

0.2$\cdot$0.8+0.2$\cdot$0.8+0.8$\cdot$0.8=0.96=P(“at least one positive test”)